# Firefox: is it possible to block update reminder for one specific extension?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, updates

I'd like to stick with Firefox extension ReadItLater version 0.9948 - but Firefox keeps reminding me that update is available.

Is there any way to get rid of reminders for this specific extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this great MozillaZine article, [Disabling update checks for individual add-ons](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Updating_extensions#Disabling_update_checks_for_individual_add-ons_-_Advanced_users).

In a nutshell:

> - Find the GUID for the extension. GUIDs are either e-mail addresses or a
>     bunch of random characters inside { }
>     brackets. The folders named after
>     extension GUIDs are in the extensions
>     folder of the [profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder). You
>     can look at the install.rdf file in
>     each folder to see what extension it's
>     for.
> - Type [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) in the address bar and press enter.
> - Right-click -> New -> Boolean
> - Name: extensions.[GUID].update.enabled
> - Value: false

replace `[GUID]` with the GUID of the extension. To find the GUID easier, open up `about:config` and use `extensions.{` as the filter. You can match the description in the **value** column with the description of the add-on in **Tools -> Add-ons** if you are unsure of which entry is the GUID you're looking for. Ths GUID is the value between the curly braces in the **Preference Name** column.

Comment: +1 nice answer, didn't know this was possible.

Comment: In my specific case: 
extensions.isreaditlater@ideashower.com.update.enabled